# Slider problem for buttons

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drupal, slider

I am using slider module for sliding the content page.
I want change the "next" and "previous" button.
When the slider page is loaded, I want to hide the "previous" button.
When I click the "next" button, the "previous" button should display, and when I go to the last slide, the "next" button should hide.

How can i do this?

I am using "Slider " module and Drupal 6.

Comment: Are you starting completely from scratch? Or do you have some code already? If so can you post it here.

Comment: Please don't post exact duplicates of the same question.  If you need more answers to this (or any other) question, add information to the question by editing it.  Let us know what you've tried so far, what is working and what isn't, or what you've found out by doing your own research.

Answer (score 0):

My idea:

What about using JQuery Paginate Buttons. They already have that feature. Maybe you can get a hint there.

Link:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination
http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/jquery/jquery-javascript-pagination.html